# How to split a pandas data frame column to multiple columns based on the text value contained

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say there is column like below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['A-line B-station 9-min C-station 3-min',
                   'D-line E-station 8-min F-line G-station 5-min',
                   'G-line H-station 1-min I-station 6-min J-station 8-min'],
                    columns=['station'])
```

A,B,C is just arbitrary characters and there are whole bunch of rows like this.

```
                                             station
0             A-line B-station 9-min C-station 3-min
1      D-line E-station 8-min F-line G-station 5-min
2  G-line H-station 1-min I-station 6-min J-stati...
```

How can we make columns like below?

```
   Line1     Station1-1   Station1-2 Station1-3   Line2    Station2-1
0  A-line    B-station    C-station    null       null     null
1  D-line    E-station    null         null       F-line   G-station
2  G-line    H-station    I-station    J-station  null     null
```

stationX-X means that Station (line number) - (order of station)

Station1-1 means first  station for first line(line1)

Station1-2 means second station for first line(line1)

Station2-1 means first  station for second line(line2)

**I tried to split by delimiter; however, it doesn't work since every row has different number of lines and stations.**

What I maybe need is to split columns based on their characters contained. For example, I could store first '-line' to Line1 and store first '-station' to station1-1.

Does anybody have any ideas how to do this?

Any small thoughts help me!

Thank you!

Comment: Why does your output on index 1 has null entries for column Station1-2 
 and Station1-3?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit to clarify that station1-1 means that "first station for line1". Likewise, station1-2 means "second station for line1". station2-1 means "first station for line2".

Comment: @shaikmoeed - I think not, more, more complicated

Comment: @yusan can you please change the question title to a more generic one,

Comment: @Shijith I approved edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create `Series` with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = df['station'].str.split(expand=True).stack()
```

Then remove values ending with `min` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html):

```
df1 = s[~s.str.endswith('min')].to_frame('data').rename_axis(('a','b'))
```

Then create counters for `line`s and for `station` rows with filtering and [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df1['Line'] = (df1[df1['data'].str.endswith('line')]
                         .groupby(level=0)
                         .cumcount()
                         .add(1)
                         .astype(str))
df1['Line'] = df1['Line'].ffill()

df1['station'] = (df1[df1['data'].str.endswith('station')]
                         .groupby(['a','Line'])
                         .cumcount()
                         .add(1)
                         .astype(str))
```

Create Series with join, replace missing values by `df1['Line']` by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1['station'] = (df1['Line'] + '-' + df1['station']).fillna(df1['Line'])
```

Reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_index('station', append=True)['data'].reset_index(level=1, drop=True).unstack()
```

`Rename` columns names - not before for avoid wrong sorted:

```
df1 = df1.rename(columns = lambda x: 'Station' + x if '-' in x else 'Line' + x)
```

Remove columns name:

```
df1.columns.name = None
df1.index.name = None
print (df1)
    Line1 Station1-1 Station1-2 Station1-3   Line2 Station2-1
0  A-line  B-station  C-station        NaN     NaN        NaN
1  D-line  E-station        NaN        NaN  F-line  G-station
2  G-line  H-station  I-station  J-station     NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Impressive. Let me digest your answer first. I'll wait for a while in case other people answer this question. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. My time is Pacific Time, so I'll digest this tomorrow.

Comment: @jezrael , can the last column heading be changed to `Station2-1`